# Using @ModelAttribute with parameter in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, modelattribute

I want to using a method @ModelAttribute able to return a string with a parameter, that's is the method present in the controller :

```
@ModelAttribute("status")
    public String getStatusDevice(String poi) {
        return deviceService.getStatus(poi);

    }
```

And the method are called in the view JSP like this :

```
    <c:set var = "activity" scope = "page" value ="${status(devicesList.information.poi)}"/>
    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${activity == 'active' }">
        <i class="material-icons">check</i>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
        <i class="material-icons">report problem</i>
      </c:otherwise> 
  </c:choose>
```

But it seems that it does not recognize the parameter because when I make a trace log the POI is null.
Can you please help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: `status` is a `String`. So not sure what you expect `value ="${status(devicesList.information.poi)}"` to do. It won't call the method, you shouldn't be calling methods from JSP's they are view only and shouldn't contain logic.

Comment: Yet it calls it because it returns me an HTTPRequest error, the method in service is : @Override
 public String getStatus(String poi) {
  String status = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/devicegateway/v1/devices/status-{poi}", String.class,poi);
  return status;
 } and the URL mapped is "http://localhost:8080/devicegateway/v1/devices/status-" so the POI is not recognized

Comment: No it won't call it. It gives you an error because a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method is always called before any `@RequestMapping` method and there is no way Spring has a way to get the `poi` parameter and it as such will fail because it is `null`.It isn't due to the call you think it makes from the JSP it fails because it tries to execute a `@RequestMapping` method.